# Measuring a negative input on unipolar supply ADC

Tags: adc

Electrocardiograms ("EKG") measure the PQRST waves in a heart beat. In the sequence, Q and S are negative.

Given that, could anyone please explain how differential signals can be fed to an ADC which is connected to unipolar supply (say 3.3 V with respect to ground)?

How can the negative part of the input signal be detected even if the device is referenced to ground?

Comment: Buffer/shift it with an instrumentation amp.

Answer (score 2):

The incoming signal is adjusted so that its maximum peak to peak signal does not exceed 3.3V and then this signal is offset with a dc voltage of 1.65V.

1.65V becomes the new 0V.

**EDIT**

I've just re-read and I think you require a differential amp level shifter. Still easy to do and same sort of principle as my 1st answer BUT information about the input and the ADC is needed if you want better details - i.e. is the ADC also differential?

Comment: i am using an analog front end(ads1298r)..

Answer (score 1):

> please explain how differential signals can be fed to an ADC which is connected to Unipolar Supply

There are many many choices of ADC that operate from a single supply and accept differential inputs. [ADC10154](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc10154.pdf) is just one of the 1000's of choices.

> How can the negative part of the input signal even be detected if the device is referenced to 0V?

Generally it can't. You still have to keep the input voltages between the ADC's power supply rails.

What you can do is offset your input signals so that they are always above 0 V.

The canonical way to do this, and at the same time convert the signal from differential to single-ended, is with an instrumentation amp. An instrumentation amp takes a differential input and outputs a single-ended output referenced to it's "REF" pin. The in-amp will, however, require bipolar supplies if the input signals will drop below ground.

In-amps are generally designed to provide high gain, low dc drift, low offset voltage, high input impedance, appropriate for amplifying dc-coupled signals. [AD621](http://www.analog.com/en/specialty-amplifiers/instrumentation-amplifiers/ad621/products/product.html) is a classic precision in-amp, though there are many others out there.